# how to create Appoinment from Android MS CRM SDK?

Tags: android, dynamics-crm

i am creating appointment using below code give **"500 Internal Server Error"**

i added all fields check it

```
Appointment objappointment = Appointment.build()
            .setSubject("Android sub")
            .setDescription("dis from device")
           .setRegardingObjectId(new EntityReference("account", UUID.fromString("0717b8e2-d00a-e611-8115-c4346bdd11d1")))
            .setOwnerId(new EntityReference("systemuser", UUID.fromString("3edb272d-2da7-4c89-9350-2f4bd4e1762b")))
            .setStateCode(new OptionSetValue(0))
            .setNew_Latitude(23.7845)
            .setNew_Longitude(73.6574)
             .setNew_City("Surat")
            .setActualStart(mDate.getTime())
            .setActualEnd(mDate1.getTime())
           .setNew_ZipPostalCode("380060")
            .setNew_Street1("Street1")
            .setNew_Street2("Street3")
            .setNew_street3("Street3")
            .setNew_StateProvince("Gujarayt")
            .setNew_CountryRegion("India")
            .setNew_Latitude(23.7845)
            .setNew_Longitude(73.6574)
            .setStatusCode(new OptionSetValue(0))
            .setPriorityCode(new OptionSetValue(2));


try {
            RestOrganizationServiceProxy restService = new RestOrganizationServiceProxy(mOrgService);
            restService.Create(objappointment,new Callback<UUID>() {
                @Override
                public void success(UUID uuid, Response response) {
                    log("sucess", uuid.toString());

                          }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    displayError(error.toString());
                    log("error", error.toString());
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            displayError(ex.getMessage());
            log("msg",ex.toString());
        }
```

another entity create successfully using above code just got error in "Appoinment"

Comment: What is it you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Could you get more details of the exception? 500 could be any exception. At least you know the request hit the server and it's failing on the CRM server side. Maybe a plugin or similar is raising the exception.

I think you have to pass the objectid to whom the annotation will be linked to (Account, Contact, or whatever...)

Is that on-premise or online CRM? If OnPremise you could enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults property in the web.config to at least get more details of the exception....

Comment: i also try using below code but got same error    Appointment objappointment = Appointment.build()
                .setSubject("Android sub")
                .setDescription("dis from device")
               .setRegardingObjectId(new EntityReference("contact", UUID.fromString("41c73e31-a128-e611-80ec-c4346bdc5eb1")))
                .setOwnerId(new EntityReference("systemuser", UUID.fromString("afed4640-505a-476d-97f5-cb16fb0ad9de")))
                .setStateCode(new OptionSetValue(0));

Comment: you can't pass the StateCode on creation.... Anyway, better to enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults setting, otherwise it'll be really hard to find the root cause. Do you have access to CRM ? Check the event viewer too...